# Is there a mac equivalent of the parsing software grammatica? It looks supremely useful

Tags: грамматика, resources

3rd year student here.

I came across [grammatica](http://www.grammatica.eu) and it looks incredibly useful for cementing grammatical structures. It would be a dream to quickly double check a structure.

Unfortunately it is windows-only and the web version is several months off (per an email exchange with the developer).

- Is there another similar resource?

If not I apologize for wasting bandwidth, but it seemed to me that such a resource would be useful to others as well.  If there is no such resource on the mac, do you have any advice as to how one should go about using short stories for grammar acquisition. I feel too passive in just reading them. Perhaps diagramming sentences?

Comment: A small suggestion (workaround). Buy a used laptop/desktop PC off ebay. It'll cost you maximum $100. You can install grammatica on the PC, and access it through the Remote Desktop from your Mac. Another alternative: install Oracle VirtualBox, and create a Windows virtual PC (this options may be more expensive, as you will need to purchase a Windows OS licence)

Comment: @cha Accessing via remote desktop will not work if you are not on the same subnet.  For example, my main machine is a laptop mac and I travel a lot, spending less than 10% of working time at home.  I am not opening the firewall of my home network to allow remote desktop connections from all and sundry.

Comment: That is why I proposed a second option: Oracle VirtualBox. If you are a student, you will be able to buy a "student" licence of Windows 8.1 OS, which should not be that expensive.

Comment: @cha this is what I ended up going with. Not Ideal, but it works! It really is a great tool.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a software tool requirement. The author could have just asked "how to run a program for Windows on Mac OS", and the problem would be solved. I don't see how this is related to the Russian language itself. Unfortunately, I can not migrate it to "Natural Language Processing" because that site is still not beta. The question would fit in there perfectly.

Comment: This belongs to software recommendations SE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wine](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) to install grammatica on MacOS.